# Re-Structuring SQL Query to be Faster

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following SQL query which currently runs and takes 1:17 (1 minute and 17 seconds) to complete.

```
SELECT R.SAMPNUM, count(R.SAMPNUM) as CTE1_O_Count 
FROM Results R 
Join SAMPLES O on R.SAMPNUM = O. SAMPNUM 
Join Files F on F.fileno = O.fileno 
where 
(R.SA = 'Released' OR (R.SA = 'Rejected' AND R.Test like '%Grass%'))
AND R.S in ('Okay',  'Good')
AND F.Type <> 'Fruit'
AND Month(F.FDATE) = Month(getdate()) AND Year(F.FDATE) = Year(getdate())
GROUP BY R.SAMPNUM
```

After some testing of the query, I noticed that altering the first *where* statement altered the executing time significantly.

1:17-

```
(R.SA = 'Released' OR (R.SA = 'Rejected' AND R.Test like '%Grass%'))
```

0:10-

```
(R.SA = 'Released'
```

0:11-

```
(R.SA = 'Released' OR (R.SA = 'Rejected'))
```

1:16-

```
(R.SA = 'Released' OR (R.SA = 'Rejected' AND R.Test = '%Grass%'))
```

With the testing results provided, the `AND R.Test` statement is significantly effecting the query. Is there a better way to re-structure this query to make it run more efficiently?

Comment: Please provide the DDL and query plan for your different scenarios.

Comment: That `Month(F.FDATE) = Month(getdate())` will force a full table scan to calculate the month value. This can't be accelerated by indexes on the date column. ` R.Test like '%Grass%'` is another thing that has to scan all rows and can't benefit from any indexes.

Comment: You can write a query with `R.SA = 'Released'` and another with `R.SA = 'Rejected' AND R.Test like '%Grass%'` and `UNION ALL` them together. Usually (your mileage may vary) it's quicker than an `OR` in the `WHERE`.

Comment: `AND Month(F.FDATE) = Month(getdate())` is the first thing I would fix, if you can. Is the logic really that you want all rows for January, regardless of year?

Comment: It's your leading wildcard on %Grass% that is killing you here. That is a nonSARGable predicate. The MONTH function is also nonSARGable but probably not as much a performance killer as that leading wildcard.

Comment: @Larnu I need all of the samples from the current Month & Year.(I've Fixed this). I plan to place this query in a Common Table Expression and Join it to another query to pull all samples with the same count of the existing sample.

Comment: Instead of `AND Month(F.FDATE) = Month(getdate()) AND Year(F.FDATE) = Year(getdate())` you should use proper date logic. `AND F.FDATE >= DATEADD(DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,GETDATE()),0) AND F.FDATE < DATEADD(DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,GETDATE())+1,0)`

Comment: @Larnu I want all released and rejected ones that contain a test with the name grass in it. I however, do not want rejected tests that don't have a grass test.

Comment: While the wildcard on `Test` unavoidably involves a scan as long as you use `%Something` (rather, than, say, only `Something%`), you can still speed up that scan by ensuring the column is `INCLUDE`d in an index that the query can use. Check the query plan to see what index(es) the "fast" executions hit to see if those can be extended. Alternatively, build a new computed column specifically to mirror the `LIKE '%Grass%'` condition and index that (if this is the only pattern you need).

Comment: Misread, @Brad , apologies.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the like scan seems to increase 1 second of time which I am not too worried about. I am more concerned about the '''AND R.TEST''' portion as this is adding 60 seconds worth of time to the execution. It seems if I use an AND in the OR portion it destroys the query time.

Comment: I don't know how you get that conclusion -- yes, the test on `Test` is (almost certainly) the problem, and the point is that this condition cannot (ever) be satisfied through an index seek no matter if the rest of the query ever could. The scan doesn't add one second -- it ensures different indexes get picked that completely change the execution plan. If you want more detailed help, [paste the plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) of the different executions. You should see the optimizer pick a substantially different approach.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for sharing that link! This will significantly help me understand this further. I greatly appreciate everyone's input!

Comment: @Larnu - SQL Between would be better still perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @JGFMK `BETWEEN` is an awful operator when dealing with dates.

Comment: beg to differ - it's semantically cleaner!

Comment: I disagree , @JGFMK . Something like `[Date] >= '20200101' AND [Date] < '20200201'` is much cleaner than `[Date] BETWEEN '20200101' AND '2020-01-31T23:59:59.9999999'` or `[Date] BETWEEN '20200101' AND DATEADD(NANOSECOND,-1, '20200201')`. Using `>=` and `<` syntax is far better to be completely inclusive when dealing with date and time values. Otherwise you'll include values exactly at midnight on the day you don't want, or exclude any values that happened after midnight on the final day without the nanosecond inclusion.

Comment: So you prefer to be verbose and reference [Date] twice? Opinions vary.. that's all I have to say. Think of column being renamed. Oh.. Look I know have twice as much work on the where clause to fix!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with referencing a column twice in a clause, @JGFMK , but there is problems with treating using `BETWEEN` with dates. `2020-01-31T00:59:32`, for example, it **not** `BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20200131'`. There's plenty of articles on this, such as [Being careless with your search conditions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/?utm_source=ssc&utm_medium=publink&utm_content=dateswrong#eighth). But we're a little off topic now.

Comment: So all you need to do is be precise in your literal definitions of the dates. This has nothing to do with the use of between per se.